# Maximum Subrectangle for very special matrices

Tags: algorithm, r

While working on an image processing task I have come across the following problem: There are n points in the unit square with coordinates $x_i$ and $y_i$, each assigned with a positive or negative weight $w_i$. Find a rectangle such that the sum of all weights of those points lying within the rectangle is positive and maximal.

By defining a proper grid, the problem can be rephrased as finding a submatrix in an n-by-n matrix A whose sum of elements is maximal. This is also known as the "maximal subrectangle problem" and has been discussed on SO before. While a brute force approach has a run-time of O(n^5), there is a kind of tricky solution with a run-time of O(n^3). It utilizes a solution for the corresponding one-dimensional problem, called ["maximal subarray problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem), with an O(n) run-time.

I have implemented both algorithms in R and can solve 100s of points in a few seconds. But with thousands of points it will be much too slow, probably even when outsourcing the loops to some Fortran or C code.

Now look at the matrix A. When assuming (w/o loss of generality) that all points have different x- or y-coordinates, A has a special form: In each row and column of A there is exactly *one* non-zero element. For matrices with this special property I assume there should be an algorithm performing the task in O(n^2) time, or even better.

Here is an example with the optimal rectangle added:

```
set.seed(723)
N <- 50; w <- rnorm(N)
x <- runif(N); y <- runif(N)
clr <- ifelse (w >= 0, "blue", "red")
plot(x, y, pch = 20, col = clr, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))
rect(0.075, 0.45, 0.31, 0.95, border="gray")
```

You see that there can be red, ie. negative, points in the optimal rectangle. It also shows that it will not suffice to solve the one-dimensional cases for the x- and y-coordinates.

I will translate the standard solution into Fortran, but I would surely like to have a more efficient algorithm at hand.

Answer (score 1):

[These guys](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/tad.takaoka/cats02.pdf) (found from the wiki page) claim to have a simpler sub-cubic solution for the 2-dimensional case.  It may be the one you're already aware of.

Comment: Thanks. Please remember that I am only interested in this very special situation where the matrix has just one non-zero element in each row and column. This property should make a much more efficient solution possible.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  A square matrix with only 1 non-zero element in each row or column is the product of a diagonal matrix and a permutation matrix.  It seems very likely that you can find some variant of the one-dimensional case as applied to the diagonal matrix, and extend it to matrices reachable by some particular class of permutations.

Comment: Yes, somehow. Unfortunately, simply applying the 1D case to the diagonal does not work. After reading articles and thinking about some practical geometric applications, this looks more like a research problem. And a reasonable solution could probably be published somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

See the accepted answer for "Maximum sum subrectangle in a sparse matrix".  For an nxn matrix with m non-zero elements, the solution there takes O(nm log n) time.  So, for you, since you have exactly n non-zero elements, this would give O(n^2 log n) time.  Probably you'll be able to handle cases with n being 50 times larger or more, vs. the standard O(n^3) solution.

Answer (score -1):

The best I can do is O(n^2 log n).

If we look at the n+1 choose 2 calls made by Kadane's 2D algorithm to Kadane's 1D algorithm on an input of your type, all but O(n) successive pairs are on 1D arrays that differ only in one element. I'm going to present a divide-and-conquer variant of Kadane's 1D; by caching the outcomes of each recursive call, only the O(log n) that involve the changed array element have to be recomputed, reducing the (amortized) running time of the inner loop from Theta(n) to Theta(log n).

```
def maxsubarray(arr, a, b):
    # this function returns a 4-tuple
    # element 0 is the max over intervals of the form [i, j)
    # element 1 is the max over intervals of the form [i, b)
    # element 2 is the max over intervals of the form [a, j)
    # element 3 is the max over intervals of the form [a, b), i.e., sum(arr[a:b])
    n = b - a
    if n == 0:
        return (0, 0, 0, 0)
    elif n == 1:
        x = arr[a]
        y = max(x, 0)
        return (y, y, y, x)
    else:
        m = a + n // 2
        l = maxsubarray(arr, a, m)
        r = maxsubarray(arr, m, b)
        return (max(l[0], r[0], l[1] + r[2]),
                max(r[1], l[1] + r[3]),
                max(l[2], l[3] + r[2]),
                l[3] + r[3])
```

Comment: Note: if you know that `arr` is nonempty, then you can delete the `n == 0` case.

Comment: Sorry, but what kind of answer is that: (1) Your code is not working correctly; have you ever tried it out, e.g. with `a=[1,-1.5,2,-1,3,-2,4,-5,6]`? (2) The claim that you can solve the 1d case in O(log n) time is wrong. An algorithm has to touch each element at least once, so the minimum is O(n). (3) Recursion will slow it down and maybe lead to "infinite recursion" for long arrays. And (4) my problem is not the 1d case (which I can solve for arrays with millions of element in less than 0.1 secs), but how to exploit the special form of the matrix.

Comment: That was a silly example. I tried your code on some longer examples (100 elements) and it didn't give the correct result. By the way: To apply such a function, it needs to return  the indices, i.e. from where to where the maximal subarray is running.

Comment: (1) I didn't test it previously, but it works fine: invoke with maxsubarray(arr, 0, len(arr)). (2) The first one takes linear time; the updates are O(log n). (3) Make it iterative then. (4) Yes I realize, which is why I told you to plug this 1D algorithm into 2D Kadane. (5) It's not very difficult to modify the maximums to remember the indices. (6) That was a rude series of comments, so I will help you with none of this.

Comment: I apologize if I sounded harsh. I have a very fast, compiled routine for the 1D case, and I do apply it to the matrix case. What makes my solution slow is the double loop through the rows of the matrix (the O(n^2) part). Therefore, I am still interested in ideas how to exploit the very special form of the matrix. Thanks.